# Android TransactionTooLargeException when opening a PDF from Intent via Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-intent, firebase-storage

I tried to open a pdf from firebase storage via an intent. The intent starts an shows the pdf, but after that the app crashes with the following error:

```
rocess: de.snapdrive.a2health, PID: 13298
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1457344 bytes
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4006)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1457344 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:748)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4636)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3998)
```

I use the following code:

```
btn_open_anamnesebogen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

            StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child("patients/" + patientid + "/docs/Anamnesebogen.pdf");

            riversRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(task.getResult().toString()), "application/pdf");
                   startActivity(intent);


                }
            });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `The intent starts an shows the pdf` Intents dont show files. Which app is started/selected by the user that displays the pdf?

Comment: What is the value of `task.getResult().toString()`?

Comment: Shouldnt you use ACTION_VIEW?

Comment: The value of task.getResult().toString() is the link to the pdf from the firebase storage. @blackapps

Comment: Google drive displays the pdf @blackapps

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` also not work @blackapps

Comment: Add a flag grand read permission.

Comment: I dont need read permission. I open the pdf file from a link. I don't download the pdf file from firebase storage I only get the direct link to open the pdf. It's a web link from the pdf. @blackapps

Comment: Install some other pdf viewers and find out that most will not display pdfs from a http url.

Comment: I tried to open the pdf via an web intent. I open the pdf link in Chrome. Chrome display the pdf, but 2 seconds later a popup shows that the app is crashed in background. Same error: `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1457800 bytes´`@blackapps

Comment: What are you saving in onSaveInstanceState()? You can start any other app with an intent without the pdf used. The fact that your activity/app goes to background is the reason.

Comment: Here you can see the pdf open, but 2 seconds later the app crashes. [link](https://prnt.sc/tya3yy) @blackapps

Comment: I dont have a `onSaveInstanceState()`@blackapps

Comment: Well then in the other overridden functions that come into play when your activity/app goes to background or gets killed.

Comment: I can fixed the problem when I add the following code into my MainActivity:

`@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {

        outState.clear();
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }` @blackapps

Comment: That is pure magic.

Comment: It sounds like you have something huge in the `View` hierarchy that is causing the crash, if you aren't saving anything in `onSaveInstanceState()`. This may also cause your app a problem if it gets pushed to the background and then comes forward again. Maybe edit your question and add your layout.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error with the following code in the MainActivity:

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {

    outState.clear();
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking this is a really bad solution. The Android framework stores the state of your `Activity` here when it goes to the background. If you clear the state, when the `Activity` comes back to the foreground it will have no saved state. Depending on what your `Activity` does, this could confuse the user.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass large set of data through intents. Instead save it in Activity A and retrieve it in Activity B and then in onDestroy method of the Activity B, clear that data.